# OpenTok with joomla

Tags: php, joomla, opentok

I am creating the basic video chat with OPENTOK api. i have the code that is working fine in core php but same code when i using with joomla 2.5. page is showing blank. code is given below.

```
 <script src='//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var apiKey = "<api key here>";
    var sessionId = "<session id>";
    var token = "<Token here>";


    TB.setLogLevel(TB.DEBUG);
    var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId); 
    session.on({ 
        streamCreated: function(event) { 
          session.subscribe(event.stream, "videos", {insertMode: 'append'}); 
        } 
    }); 
    session.connect(token, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        session.publish('myPublisherDiv', {width: 264, height: 198}); 
      }
    });
  </script>
  <div id="videos">
    <div id="myPublisherDiv" style="margin-bottom:10px"></div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where is inserted the code above?

If you are creating an extension then in order to add javascript in joomla, you need for example  to do this:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    window.event("domready", function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });
');
?>
```

If you have to include js files:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

for further information you can visit (which is the source of the examples):
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript